# delphi firmonkey how to draw on canvas an antialised disc?

Tags: android, delphi, graphics, firemonkey

On Delphi with Firemonkey for android, how to draw on paintbox or any canvas an anti-aliased disc ? Also in general is their any solution to make controls anti-aliased on firmonkey ?

Comment: Does setting `Form1.Quality:= HighQuality;` help?

Comment: yes a lot ;) but using Jbitmap is more efficient :)